# Homotopy unites of a differential graded algebra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

I apologize in advance if the question is too basic.
Let $A$ be a differential graded algebra and $H^{0}A$ the 0-cohomology of $A$ (which is an ordinary ring) and $A^0$ is the 0-level of $ A$ . An element $a\in A^0$ is said to be homotopy invertible if there exists $x\in A^0$ such that $[xa-1]=[ax-1]=0\in H^0 A$.

I was wondering if there exists a weak equivalence of differential graded algebras $A\rightarrow B$ such that an element $ b\in B^0$ is strictly invertible if and only if it is homotopy invertible. 
Thank you in advance.

PS: The differential graded algebra A is not supposed to be bounded.

Comment: In order to take cohomology classes you must first assume that $xa-1$ and $ax-1$ are cocycles, which amounts to $xa$ and $ax$ being cocycles.

Comment: Fernando, it is by definition since I wrote [ax-1]... Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: I have undeleted this question which you have deleted six years ago. -- Please do not self-delete your useful questions!